# PyOpenGL: glCreateProgram() causes NullFunctionError

Tags: python, shader, pyopengl

I am just trying to run exactly this sample code to test the installation: https://gist.github.com/ousttrue/c4ae334fc1505cdf4cd7

It fails on glCreateProgram() eventhough i have instaled PyOpenGL, PyOpenGL-accelerate and freeglut using the whl files from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
  packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 410, in __call__ 
  self.__name__, self.__name__, 
  OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function 
  glCreateProgram, check for bool(glCreateProgram) before calling
```

The Code from this tutorial which does not include a shader works just fine: https://noobtuts.com/python/opengl-introduction
So it is just glCreateProgram() that fails.

I have also copied the DLL files into SystenWOW64 and System32, as well as the folder my Script runs in.

Has anyone an idea where to search for the error.

I run Windows 10 64 Bit with 64 bit Python 3.5 via Remote Desktop

Comment: For [`glCreateProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCreateProgram.xhtml), at least OpenGL 2.0 or OpenGL ES 2.0 is required. Use `print( glGetString(GL_VERSION) )` (right before `initialize()`) to print the OpenGL version.

Comment: Windows Remote Desktop uses software OpenGL 1.1, which does not support shaders. Try a [workaround](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c8295ef8-3711-4576-9293-2c4965280165/opengl-and-remote-desktop?forum=winserverTS) or [RemoteFx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX).

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem :)

Comment: For other check also that the glCreate functions are called after a rendering context has been created (nor by glut or any other way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that, when you log in on remote desktop you somehow can't access the graphics card. Connecting the screen directly to the computer solved the problem.